# how to calculate image gradient

Tags: java

My instructor gave us the pseudocode:

```
grad = abs(im(x+1,y)-im(x-1,y)) + abs(im(x,y+1)-im(x,y-1))
```

to calculate the gradient of an image for an edge detector we are making.  I thought that the way this pseudocode would look like is:

```
int grad = Math.abs(img.getRGB(i+1,j)-img.getRGB(i-1,j)) + 
           Math.abs(img.getRGB(i,j+1)-img.getRGB(i,j-1));
```

he said this code would only get the R value of a color.  I'm having trouble understanding this.  Could someone help me understand how to use this formula to get an entire color gradient? (this formula would go in a nested for loop and apply to every pixel)

Answer (score 1):

Your instructor means that you need to get the `R`ed for each pixel. You can either fiddle with the bits that are returned from `getRGB(x, y)` to get just the red, or you can put the RGB value into a `Color` and extract it that way.

```
public int getRed(BufferedImage image, int x, int y)
{
    // Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), true); if you care about alpha
    Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

    return color.getRed();
}
```

This will [give you a value between [0, 255]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed%28%29). If you want a value between [0, 1], then you need to divide by `255.0`.

Bit shifting would be a faster solution, but this is the easier solution and it is likely fast enough. For reference, red would be bits [16, 23].